# Javascript - Function not recognized when js file is called using createElement stuff

Tags: javascript

I have coding like this:

```
<script language="javascript" src="test.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

    mp.init({
    app_id  : 'hd32y4328r3meh2423em',
    version : '1.0'
    });

</script>
```

And inside **test.js** like this :

```
var mp = {};
    mp.init = function(vars) {
        var obj = Object.create(vars); // create obj
        console.log(obj); // all
        alert(obj);
        //return obj;
    };
```

But the **mp.init function ()** it is not recognized when i load **test.js** using createElement like code below:

```
<script language="javascript">
    // Load the JS asynchronously       
    (function() {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.src = 'mpsdk.js';
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();


    // We have a simple cars object     
    mp.init({
    app_id  : 'hd32y4328r3meh2423em',
    version : '1.0'
    });

</script>
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: DOM element insertion is not blocking. The rest of your script will run and then mpsdk.js will be loaded.

Comment: You need to wait until the js file is loaded.`mp.init` is _called_ before `mpsdk.js` is loaded/evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Call function after script loading**

Try this-

```
function() {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.src = 'mpsdk.js';
        s.addEventListener('load', function(){
        //script loaded do stuff here
         // We have a simple cars object     
         mp.init({
         app_id  : 'hd32y4328r3meh2423em',
         version : '1.0'
         });
        });
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
```

**Or
Using callback function on load.**

```
     var onLoadScript = function(callback) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.src = 'mpsdk.js';
        s.addEventListener('load',callback);//callback on load

        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
     };
onLoadScript(function(e){
        //script loaded do stuff here
         // We have a simple cars object     
         mp.init({
         app_id  : 'hd32y4328r3meh2423em',
         version : '1.0'
         });
};
```

Comment: When recommending to write a loader instead of using an existing one, you should probably mention that there are various problems e.g. with older IE (below 10)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're executing the code *synchronously*, while the script is loaded *asynchronously*. So, when you call `mp.init` the script hasn't been loaded yet.

You have to either listen for the `load` event (for IE9+ and standard browsers) or `readystatechange` event (for IE8-) checking for `readyState === "complete"` and then call `mp.init`.

But I suggest you to save all the hassle by using one of the many AMD loaders around (RequireJS, curl, ...), or even jQuery's `$.getScript`.